# How to set two separate States with Redux Toolkit?

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to establish two separate states with Redux Toolkit, one called `posts` and another called `countTest`. However, at the moment the two states share the same value.

[image]

`posts` is set to display a value  of `[]` and `countTest` is set to display a value of  `0`. How do I differentiate the two states to display their unique value?

**My actions file**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { database, auth } from "../firebase";
import { ref, set } from "firebase/database";

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: "posts",
  initialState: {
    value: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    createAccount: (state, action) => {
      const user = auth.currentUser;
      const uid = user.uid;

      set(ref(database, `users/${uid}`), {
        email: action.payload.email,
        name: action.payload.name,
      });
    },
  },
});

export const testSlice = createSlice({
  name: "countTest",
  initialState: { value: 0 },
  reducers: {
    incrementAmount: (state, action) => {
      state.value = state.value + 1;
    },
    decrementAmount: (state, action) => {
      state.value = state.value - 1;
    },
  },
});

export const { createAccount, countTest } = counterSlice.actions;

export default counterSlice.reducer;
```

**My store  file**

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import counterReducer from "./actions";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    posts: counterReducer,
    countTest: counterReducer,
  },
});
```

I know in my store file I'm using `counterReducer` without specifically referring to the actions `createAccount` and `countTest`. How do I go about retrieving the unique values of each and displaying in store? Do I need to create a separate file for each action (is this best practice?) instead of having all the actions in one file?

Thank  you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `createAction` (on an another file or on one of your slice import action from it) and use extraReducer.

Doc :
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice (the last exemple)

Example `createAction`:

```
export const incrementAll = createAction("incrementAll");
```

use on your slices :

```
reducers : {//what you have for other things},
extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(incrementAll, (state) => {
      state.value++;
    });
```

See the doc for more information or comment here if you need more explanation